# Token Aliases in Antlr

Tags: antlr4

I have rules that look something like this:

```
INTEGER           : [0-9]+;
field3     : INTEGER COMMA INTEGER;
```

In the parsed tree I get an List called INTEGER with two elements.

I would rather find a way for each of the elements to be named.

But if I do this:

```
INTEGER  : [0-9]+;
DOS      : INTEGER;
UNO      : INTEGER;
field3     : UNO COMMA DOS;
```

I still get the array of INTEGERs.

Am I doing it right and I just need to dig deeper to figure out what is wrong?

Is there some kind of syntax to alias INTEGER as UNO just for this command (that is actually what I would prefer)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use labeling to identify the subterms:

```
field     : a=INTEGER COMMA b=INTEGER;
```

The `FieldContext` class will be generated with two additional class fields:

```
TerminalNode a;
TerminalNode b;
```

The corresponding `INTEGER` instances will be assigned to these fields. So, no aliasing is actually required in most cases.

However, there can be valid reasons to change the named type of a token and typically is handled in the lexer through the use of modes, actions, and predicates. For example, using modes, if `INTEGER` alternates between `UNO` and `DOS` types:

```
lexer grammar UD ;

UNO : INT -> mode(two);

mode two;
    DOS : INT -> mode(default);

fragment INT : [0-9]+ ;
```

When to do the mode switch and whether a different specific approach might be more appropriate will depend on details not provided yet.

Comment: Great answer.  Here is how it could be improved: comment on what makes good names for the aliases.